# Salt-Stack require statement

Tags: salt-stack

I've started playing with Salt. I could not find any info on how to make a state depend on multiple other states.

```
state_a:
  module.run:
    - name: my.module
    - m_name: name_a

state_b:
  module.run:
    - name: my.module
    - m_name: name_b

state_c:
  module.run:
    - name: my.module
    - m_name: name_c

    - require:
      - module: ...
```

How can I make `state_c` to `require` both `state_a` and `state_b`?

**Bonus question**: What is the rationale behind using `Key: Single Value` structure for defining dependencies in Salt?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work in most cases:

```
state_c:
  module.run:
    - name: my.module
    - m_name: name_c
    - require:
      - module: state_a
      - module: state_b
```

Also, regarding Salt's usage of lists of single-value dicts instead of flat dictionaries: I think it's partly because of cases like this one where you need multiple identical keys, and partly as a way to simulate an ordereddict for cases when order matters. I'm not a salt developer, though.

Comment: Thanks. After reading your answer I understand how stupid the question is. YAML confused me a bit.